# Is it possible to read file system from sd card in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I am creating a media player in html/js which will read and display audio/video present on sd card with file structure. I can read single/multiple files with File Api but an't find anything to read complete directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and found 
1.) You can read any file if you know the path using HTML 5 File API.
2.) No, you cannot read whole directory, you can read only files.